# Keeping CharFields in array instead of multiple variables

Tags: django, django-models

Right now I'm using various variables to store fields, and it works well, but I'd like to move them to lists. Is there a way to do this?

What I have now:

```
lessonNameFirst = models.CharField('8:30-10:00', max_length = 50)
additInfoFirst = models.CharField('Additional info', max_length = 50)

lessonNameSecond = models.CharField('10:15-11:45', max_length = 50)
additInfoSecond = models.CharField('Additional info', max_length = 50)

lessonNameThird = models.CharField('12:30-14:00', max_length = 50)
additInfoThird = models.CharField('Additional info', max_length = 50)

lessonNameFourth = models.CharField('14:10-15:40', max_length = 50)
additInfoFourth = models.CharField('Additional info', max_length = 50)
```

What I'm looking for:

```
lessonName = [
    models.CharField('8:30-10:00', max_length = 50),
    models.CharField('8:30-10:00', max_length = 50),
    models.CharField('8:30-10:00', max_length = 50),
    models.CharField('8:30-10:00', max_length = 50)
]

additInfo = [
    models.CharField('Additional info', max_length = 50),
    models.CharField('Additional info', max_length = 50),
    models.CharField('Additional info', max_length = 50),
    models.CharField('Additional info', max_length = 50)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) if you're using PostgreSQL as the database.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class ModelName(models.Model):
    lessonName =  ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 50))
    additInfo = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 50))
]
```

Refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes) for connecting Django with PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am using sqlite3 as a db, is there a way for sqlite3? And if not, can I switch to PostgreSQL?

Comment: You can store the elements in a TextField with a delimiter between each element if you want to use SQLite, but I would not recommend that as it is not a good practice under normal circumstances. I'd recommend switching to PostgreSQL instead, regarding which I've added the link in the answer above.